# Run two different projects in same VPS using Laradock

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock

I am new in Docker. Me and my team decided to use Docker (Laradock) to run our application because we have a several project and using different specification.

Imagine we have 2 different project and want to run in same time, we have init laradock in each project and have custom our port in .env file so not conflict each other. Like PMA_PORT=8082 in project 1 and PMA_PORT=8085 in project 2 and so do in another port config.

When we run project 1 using command `docker-compose up -d phpmyadmin apache2 mariadb`, it runs well as expected. But the problem is when the project1 is run in background and we want to run project2 in background too. I use command `docker-compose up -d phpmyadmin nginx mysql` in the project 2. It also run well, but the project 1 is down although we have using different port.

This is the log info when I run that command

```
Removing laradock_mysql_1
Removing laradock_nginx_1
Recreating laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ... done
Starting fa6ba29f1fc8_laradock_mysql_1 ... done
Recreating laradock_phpmyadmin_1       ... done
Recreating laradock_workspace_1        ... done
Recreating laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done
Recreating d18266c4f247_laradock_nginx_1 ... done
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Laradock outside of your projects folders and you won't need to change ports or anything else.

Like the documentation says here: https://laradock.io/getting-started/#B

Your folder structure should be like that:

- Projects (or whatever name you want)

  - laradock
  - Project_1
  - Project_2

Then, when you run the docker-compose up command inside the laradock folder, both your projects will be up and running.

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: But can I use diferent PHP_VERSION for each project? I see the config is in .env file but the .env file is in the laradock folder. So we setup laradoc in each project

Comment: If we can use diferent version of PHP in each project, this is what we wanted

Comment: I see. Then you can follow this link and follow the comments, it's really easy to setup if you read everything and do as they say: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/956